# Identifying some parts of Query Plan in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-execution-plan

I have recently encountered a problem I have hard time working around. I have to tune a rather nasty query that extensively uses - in many forms and on several layers - XML. The problem is that while it is easy to spot the slow part of the whole process - Table Valued Function [XML Reader] - it is rather hard to map it to any specific part of the query. The properties does not indicate on which XML column does this particular object work and I'm really puzzled why is that. Generally, it is relatively easy to map object to a part of a query but these XML objects are giving me a pause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you supply an example query/plan that illustrates your problem?

Comment: I hope it would be downloadable: http://speedy.sh/9S2zh/examplePlan.zip

Comment: Was my question that stupid or that much unanswerable?

Comment: Just tried to answer it only to find that the zip file seems to be corrupted. Doesn't open on my machine successfully anyway.